# Publishing Mercurial Respository on apache problem

Tags: apache, mercurial, repository, cgi

I have a repository in here http://repos.joomlaguruteam.com/

I can browse it but I can clone it.
Every time I clone it I have this error

```
hg clone http://repos.joomlaguruteam.com/hello
destination directory: hello
requesting all changes
abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

and the access log have that

```
115.5.95.59 - - [10/Feb/2011:04:20:33 -0600] "GET /hello?pairs=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000000000000000000000000000000000&cmd=between HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "-" "mercurial/proto-1.0"
115.5.95.59 - - [10/Feb/2011:04:20:34 -0600] "GET /hello?cmd=heads HTTP/1.1" 200 41 "-" "mercurial/proto-1.0"
115.5.95.59 - - [10/Feb/2011:04:20:34 -0600] "GET /hello?cmd=changegroup&roots=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 HTTP/1.1" 404 597 "-" "mercurial/proto-1.0"
```

What is the problem.

### I really hope somebody can help me with that.

Thanks,
Yuan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could clone this by using `uncompressed transfer.`

- If you are using TortoiseHg, then check the box Use uncompressed transfer
- If you are using command-line, then use `--uncompressed` flag

  hg clone --uncompressed http://repos.joomlaguruteam.com/hello

Comment: Hi, but Why I have to uncompressed the transfer, is there anyway that I can config it to allow
hg clone http://repos.joomlaguruteam.com/hello

Comment: @Yuan Chen. This could be due to version mismatch between client and server. http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UpgradeNotes has some info on --uncompressed

Comment: @Raghum Hi, I can't pull from the server or check incoming please look at this stackoverflow.com/q/4969858/507172